# Stop printing line of text from a file after a character appears a second time

Tags: java, string, file, file-handling

I am currently trying to stop printing a line of text after a `,` character is read on that line a second time from a text file. Example; `14, "Stanley #2 Philips Screwdriver", true, 6.95`. Stop reading and print out the text after the `,` character is read a second time. So the output text should look like `14, "Stanley #2 Philips Screwdriver"`. I tried to use a limit on the regex to achieve this but, it just omits all the commas and prints out the entire text. This is what my code looks like so far;

```
public static void fileReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("/Users/14077/Downloads/inventory.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String test = "4452";
        
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] itemID = line.split(",", 5); //attempt to use a regex limit
            if(itemID[0].equals(test)) {
                for(String a : itemID)
                System.out.println(a);
            }//end if 
            
        }//end while    
        
    }//end fileReader
```

I also tried to print just part of the text up until the first comma like;

```
String itemID[] = line.split(",", 5);
       System.out.println(itemID[0]);
```

But no luck, it just prints 14. Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: isn't this just: itemID[1] ? based on your stated desired output, no matter the split limit

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I overthought the output! This worked perfectly, thanks for simplifying it!

Comment: @FlavianIuga Yes it is, I overthought the output! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about something using String.indexOf and String.substring functions (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
int indexSecondOccurence = line.indexOf(",", line.indexOf(",") + 1);
System.out.println(line.substring(0, indexSecondOccurence + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to modify your code as follows.

```
...
        String[] itemID = line.split(",", 3); //attempt to use a regex limit
        if(itemID[0].equals(test)) {
            System.out.println(String.join (",", itemID[0],itemID[1]));
        }
...
```

The split() call will produce an array with maximum 3 elements. First two will be the string pieces that you need. The last element is the remaining "tail" of the original string.
Now we only need to merge the pieces back with the join() method.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With `String.split`, the limit parameter is going to be the maximum number of `String` array values you want returned.
For example, `"A,B,C,D"`, with a limit of 2 will return `["A", "B,C,D"]`.

In terms of the use of `String.split` on the data.
If the quoted text item, in this case, "Stanley #2 Philips Screwdriver", is guaranteed not to contain a `,`, then `split` is the method to go with.
From there, your `0` index will contain `"14"`, and your `1` index will contain `"Stanley #2 Philips Screwdriver"`.

In regard to printing your data, just concatenate the values.

```java
String itemID[] = line.split(",", 5);
System.out.println(itemID[0] + ", " + itemID[1]);
```

So, in conclusion, you can do the following with the given data
`14, "Stanley #2 Philips Screwdriver", true, 6.95`.

```java
String string = "14, \"Stanley #2 Philips Screwdriver\", true, 6.95";
String[] strings = string.split(", ");
String id = strings[0];
String description = strings[1];
System.out.println(id);
System.out.println(description);
```

Output

```
14
"Stanley #2 Philips Screwdriver"
```